# exclude sidebar from specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to exclude the sidebar from one more specific page

I have this:

```
<?php if (is_page('Forum')) { } else { ?>

<?php get_sidebars(); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

But I want to add another page

I tried this:

```
<?php if (is_page('Forum'), ('Shop') { } else { ?>

<?php if (is_page('Forum','Shop') { } else { ?>
```

and

But none of those seem to work.

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if (is_page('Forum') || is_page('Shop')) { } else {
```

You need to use the OR operator to combine two boolean expressions. That is if the page is Forum OR if the page is Shop then...